# Combine character vector with data.frame and complete table

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr

I have a data frame with id-numbers, a product variable and a dummy variable that tells if a products has been bought or not.

```
set.seed(2019)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(id = rep.int(c(1:5), 5),
                 bought = 1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(product = c("244.1","455.2","266.3","777.4","111.1"))
```

In addition to this I have a vector with products that I know have not been bought that I would like to add to the data frame.

```
products <- c("100.4", "500.1", "200.1", "121.6", "251.7", "215.1", "172.2")
```

That is, for each user I would like the non-bought products and set bought = 0.

One way to do this is to create a data frame out of the vector and bind it to the original data frame.

```
products <- data.frame(product = products)
products$id <- NA
products$bought <- 0

products <- products[, c(2, 3, 1)]

df <- bind_rows(df, products)
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector
```

Then I can use `data.table` to complete the table, turn every `NA = 0` and if I want filter away every observation with `id = NA`. (I could use `tidyr::complete()` as well, but the original data.frame is very large so I prefer `data.table`)

```
setDT(df)[CJ(id = id, product = product, unique = TRUE), on = .(id, product)][
  is.na(bought), bought := 0][]
#>     id bought product
#>  1: NA      0   100.4
#>  2: NA      0   111.1
#>  3: NA      0   121.6
#>  4: NA      0   172.2
#>  5: NA      0   200.1
#>  6: NA      0   215.1
#>  7: NA      0   244.1
#>  8: NA      0   251.7
#>  9: NA      0   266.3
#> 10: NA      0   455.2
#> 11: NA      0   500.1
#> 12: NA      0   777.4
#> 13:  1      0   100.4
#> 14:  1      1   111.1
#> 15:  1      0   121.6
```

However, the approach with creating a data.frame from the vector seems rather verbose and I would rather not add the rows with `id = NA`. Is there a more neat way to combine a vector with a data.frame and complete it?

<sup>Created on 2019-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Anything wrong with `add_row(df, product = products, bought = 0, id=NA)` ?

Comment: Hm, yeah, I would rather not add rows with `id = NA` if it is possible to avoid it. Furthermore, I love dplyr, but my table is rather large so I would prefer a `data.table` approach.

Comment: What do you want the `id` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with data.table:

```
products <- c("100.4", "500.1", "200.1", "121.6", "251.7", "215.1", "172.2")

df <- setDT(df)
rbindlist(lapply(unique(df$id),function(ID){
  rbind(df[id == ID],data.table(product = products,id = ID, bought = 0))
}))
```

You could consider also merging the two data frame using that dtaa frame:

```
products <- data.frame(product = rep(products,each = length(unique(df$id))), 
                                     id = rep(unique(df$id),length(unique(products))))
```